# How to load non-js files in Dojo define

Tags: javascript, configuration, path, dojo, intern

Can you load non-js files in the Dojo define([...]) function? If so, how do I do this? Because I tried to load an html file like

```
define([
   "StaticViews/Module/Views.html"], 
        function(view) {
         .... 
    }
)
```

But I get an error message in my console along the lines of...

```
DEBUG: 'failed to load resource (C:/StaticViews/Module/Views.html.js)'
```

It automatically adds ".js" to the path, and thats a file that doesn't exist. How do I load non-js files?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To load text resources, you'll need to use an AMD plugin such as [dojo/text](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/text.html):

```js
define(["dojo/text!StaticViews/Module/Views.html"], function (view) {
  ...
});
```